# Docker Bash prompt does not display color output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

I use the command `docker run --rm -it govim bash -l` to run Docker images, but it does not display color output.

If I `source ~/.bash_profile` or run `bash -l` again, output will then correctly be output with color.

[Bash Prompt Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TIBo.png)

[My bash_profile and bash_prompt](https://github.com/tthanh/dotfiles/tree/master/bash) files.

Comment: What happens if you source `.bash_prompt` from `.bashrc` (where you used to set `PS1` manually, instead of from `.bash_profile`? (That's technically more correct; you might want to set `PS1` for an interactive shell that isn't also a login shell.)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The [OP SolomonT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4186029/solomont) reports that [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/) with [`env`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) do work:

```
docker run --rm -it -e "TERM=xterm-256color" govim bash -l
```

---

And [Fernando Correia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376366/fernando-correia) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493456/docker-bash-prompt-not-display-color/33499558?noredirect=1#comment67978728_33499558):

> To get both color support and make `tmux` work, I combined both examples:

```
docker exec -it my-container env TERM=xterm-256color script -q -c "/bin/bash" /dev/null
```

---

As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) commented (earlier answer), `.bash_profile` is sourced (itis an interactive shell), since [`bash_prompt`](https://github.com/tthanh/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/bash_prompt#L113-L114) is [called by `.bash_profile`](https://github.com/tthanh/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/bash_profile#L17-L18).

But [docker issue 9299](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9299) illustrates that `TERM` doesn't seem to be set right away, forcing the users to open another bash with:

```
docker exec -ti test env TERM=xterm-256color bash -l
```

You have similar color issues with [issue 8755](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755#issuecomment-60813351).

To [illustrate/reproduce the problem](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755#issuecomment-101807288):

```
docker exec -ti $CONTAINER_NAME tty
not a tty
```

The [current workaround](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755#issuecomment-83403289) is :

```
docker exec -ti `your_container_id` script -q -c "/bin/bash" /dev/null
```

Both are supposing you have a running container first, which might not be convenient here.

Comment: I read all link you list and find out when run docker with env TERM="xterm-256color", my bash prompt display color again. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SolomonT Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Can you review it?

Comment: I missed the `-t` flag, that one is important for this to work.

Comment: To get both color support and make `tmux` work, I combined both examples: `docker exec -it my-container env TERM=xterm script -q -c "/bin/bash" /dev/null`

Comment: @FernandoCorreia Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Should the command for tmux and colors in the answer set the TERM to `xterm-256color` and not just `xterm`?

Comment: @fraxture Not sure: if you can test it, let me know and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @fraxture OK, thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 23):

**Adding -t is working for me:**

```
docker exec -t vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: Also worked with `docker run`, no `-e` needed.

Comment: I needed -t along with --env "TERM=xterm-256color"

Comment: This actually worked for me. Kinda surprised TBH.

Comment: simple and efficient

Comment: `-t` is enough to get access to the basic 16-color palette (probably good enough for most).  But you _**also**_ need the `-e "TERM=xterm-256color"` if you want to use the rest of the extended 256-color ANSI palette.

Answer (score 14):

Based on [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493456/docker-bash-prompt-does-not-display-color-output/33499558#33499558) I adding the following to my Dockerfile (which allows me to run the container without typing the environment variables on the command line every time):

```
ENV TERM xterm-256color
#... more stuff
CMD ["bash", "-l"]
```

And sure enough it works with:

```
docker run -it my-image:tag
```

For `tmux` to work with color, in my `~/.tmux.conf` I need:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

and for UTF-8 support in `tmux`, in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias tmux='tmux -u'
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:26
ENV TERM xterm-256color
RUN dnf upgrade -y && \
    dnf install golang tmux git vim -y && \
    mkdir -p /app/go/{bin,pkg,src} && \
    echo 'export GOPATH=/app/go' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
    curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
        https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim && \
    git clone https://github.com/farazdagi/vim-go-ide.git \
        ~/.vim_go_runtime && \
    bash ~/.vim_go_runtime/bin/install && \
    echo "alias govim='vim -u ~/.vimrc.go'" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "alias tmux='tmux -u'" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo 'set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"' >> ~/.tmux.conf

CMD ["bash", "-l"]
```

The Dockerfile builds an image based off [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) 26, updates it, installs a few packages (Git, Vim, golang and tmux), installs the pathogen plugin for Vim, then it installs a Git repository from here [vim-go-ide](https://github.com/farazdagi/vim-go-ide) and finally does a few tweaks to a few configuration files to get color and UTF-8 working fine. You just need to add persistent storage, probably mounted under /app/go.

If you have an image with all the development tools already installed, just make a `Dockerfile` with `ENV` statement and add the commands to modify the configuration files in a `RUN` statement without the installation commands and use your base image in the `FROM` statement. I prefer this solution because I'm lazy and (besides the initial setup) it saves typing when you want to run the image.

[Using Vim and plugins within tmux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL5ow.png)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33499558/2209946), I made this Bash function:

```bash
drun() { # start container with the specified entrypoint and colour terminal
    if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
        echo "drun needs 2+ arguments: image entrypoint" >&2
        return
    fi
    docker run -ti -e "TERM=xterm-256color" "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is something that you'd have to implement manually. My container has Python, so here's how I print in color using a single line:

***Example Docker file:***

```
FROM django:python3
RUN python -c "print('\033[90m   HELLO_WORLD   \033[0m')"
RUN python -c "print('\033[91m   HELLO_WORLD   \033[0m')"
RUN python -c "print('\033[92m   HELLO_WORLD   \033[0m')"
RUN python -c "print('\033[93m   HELLO_WORLD   \033[0m')"
RUN python -c "print('\033[94m   HELLO_WORLD   \033[0m')"
RUN python -c "print('\033[95m   HELLO_WORLD   \033[0m')"
RUN python -c "print('\033[96m   HELLO_WORLD   \033[0m')"
RUN python -c "print('\033[97m   HELLO_WORLD   \033[0m')"
RUN python -c "print('\033[98m   HELLO_WORLD   \033[0m')"
```

***Standard terminal:***

[image: Print console colors using terminal command in a single line]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following line to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo PS1="'"'\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\ \033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '"'" >> /app/.bashrc
```

Change the `/app/.bashrc` to where your `.bashrc` file is in the docker.

If you want `ls` command to have colors too add this line:

```
RUN echo alias ls="'"'ls --color=auto'"'" >> /app/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding `-e "color_prompt=yes"` worked for me.

```
docker run -it -e "color_prompt=yes" my-image:tag
```