# Docker Bash Has No Colour

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

When I run

```
docker run -i -t python /bin/bash
```

the resulting terminal has no color.

I've looked at the following links and they haven't helped:

[Docker bash prompt not display color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493456/docker-bash-prompt-not-display-color)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/Bp4BaWRw6k4

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9299

I'm using the Docker Quickstart Terminal from the Docker Toolbox on Windows 10. I have docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e.

Comment: If you build your docker with a Dockerfile, look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72879716/8786297

Answer (score 8):

To fix this you need to update the `~/.bashrc` file.

Adding something like this (borrowed from the default Ubuntu `~/.bashrc` file) should do the trick:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```

Once you've updated the `~/.bash` file, you need to reload the file by running `source ~/.bashrc`.

You may want to create your own dockerfile which does this automatically.