# How to enable colors in a Docker container?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

## Context

I have a Docker Compose with which I run several containers. My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: ../application-web/
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    tty: true
    # Add a volume to link php code on the host and inside the container
    volumes:
     - ${application_PATH}:/usr/share/application
     - ${application_PATH}/docker_files/docker-assistant:/usr/share/assistant
    depends_on:
     - custom-php
     - custom-mysql
    links:
     - custom-php:custom-php
     - custom-mysql:custom-mysql

  custom-php:
    build: ../application-php/
    ports:
     - "50:50"
    tty: true
    volumes:
     - ${application_PATH}:/usr/share/application
     - ${application_PATH}/docker_files/docker-assistant:/usr/share/assistant

  custom-mysql:
    build: ../application-mysql/
    tty: true
    volumes:
     - ${MYSQL_DATA_PATH}:${MYSQL_DATA_PATH}
     - ${application_PATH}/sql:/usr/share/sql
     - /tmp/mysql:/var/data/mysql
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=applicationdb
     - MYSQL_USER=root
     - TZ=Europe/Paris
```

We use the `custom-php` container to run unit tests in command line. Before using Docker, unit tests displayed colors in the terminal (green if everything is fine, red for each error, skipped tests in blue).

## Problem

Now, return of unit tests are all in the same color. Plus when I connect myself to a running container using `docker exec -it compose_custom-php_1 bash`, it doesn't display color either.

I tried to add the environment variable TERM=xterm like this post suggest: [Docker bash prompt not display color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493456/docker-bash-prompt-not-display-color).
I put it in my Dockerfile, and it works because some commands that was not working now can be executed (e.G. `ctrl` + `L`). But not the colors...

## Question

What is my problem? What am I doing wrong and how can I enable colors in Docker containers?

Comment: That depends on the details of the software running your unit tests. Maybe it's checking `isatty(0)` (or `isatty(1)`). Maybe it needs different terminfo content. Makes more sense to investigate that specific piece of software where the decision about whether to colorize output is being made than to hunt around at the higher layers.

Comment: ...to be clear: **bash itself has no control over the content of output written by programs it starts, including color codes contained in that output**. Those programs write their output directly to the same file descriptor bash itself uses (except when redirections &c. explicitly modify this); bash has no say in what that content is, and thus in whether it contains color codes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I also tried to just connect myself to a container and run some commands in it like `ls -la` which on my computer returns colorized output. In the container, it returns non-colorized output.

Comment: ...which doesn't have anything to do with Docker itself, and everything to do with your copy of `ls` and how it's configured (ie. the value of the `LS_COLORS` environment variable). If your container runs a minimal distribution with Busybox, the copy of `ls` it includes may not have color support at all.

Comment: About `isatty`, you will notice that I activate tty mode in the `docker-compose.yml` for all my containers.

Comment: (and `ls` is not part of bash -- see again, "not bash's decision whether tools it runs colorize their output").

Comment: btw, is `xterm` really the same TERM you're running with on the outside, as opposed to something more modern like `screen-256color`?

Comment: ...and just for the heck of it, let's try something: `blue=$(tput setaf 4); reset=$(tput setaf 0); printf 'blue=%q\n' "$blue"; printf '%s\n' "${blue}this should be blue${reset}"`. With that done, two questions: (1) What's on the line after `blue=`? (2) Is the `this should be blue` text rendered in blue? (3) Do the results differ from what you get in your local terminal? (4) Do they still differ even after you set TERM to an exact match?

Comment: Ok, for the host I have `TERM=xterm-256color`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144475/discussion-between-darckcrystale-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but this made the difference for me. I was not getting coloured output despite running my container with

`docker run -e "TERM=xterm-256color" image_name:latest`

I then added a `.bashrc` file on the host and invoked with

```
docker run -e  "TERM=xterm-256color" \
         image_name:latest \
         /bin/bash --init-file .bashrc
```

This worked for me.

I also needed to run other stuff for my `init` file, so then I created `bashrc` (no dot) that consisted of:

```
#bashrc file (no dot)
source ./my-real-init-file
source ./.bashrc
```

and invoked as:

```
docker run -e  "TERM=xterm-256color" \
         image_name:latest \
         /bin/bash --init-file bashrc
```

This also worked for me.

The trick is to have colour enabled in the `.bashrc` file

```bash
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```