# How to open shell with colours using AWS ECS execute-command?

Tags: bash, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm using execute-command to open a shell in a AWS Fargate container:

```
aws ecs execute-command --cluster MtStack-MyCluster7G3C63FE-D8338439438C \
    --task d5d35723871267123672312a \
    --interactive \
    --command "/bin/bash"
```

The does not show any colours. Is there a way to enable colours?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33499558/1032785

Comment: @jordanm thanks for the link to the solution, but could you explain how it answers my question?